# Can't change the access time of a file

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

i cant change the access time of any file i create.
i tried the `touch -a`, `touch -ad`, `touch -t` commands, but the access time in the `stat` utility stays the same.
Can you please help me to modify the access time of the file, and the change time [if possible].
Thank You.

Comment: Sometimes changes to the filesystem are not written to physical media immediately. Try forcing the update by issuing `sync` through the terminal before using `stat`

Comment: What is the file you are trying to change, what is the location?

Comment: To increase performance, atime is often disabled, check `grep atime /etc/fstab`. `touch` changes mtime, so it should work, what exact command are you running?

Comment: What is the underlying FS ? Are you using any lvm / fs snapshots ?

Comment: @hmayag Buffering on top of the physical media is irrelevant here: the kernel still sees changes in the cache even if they haven't been written to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu, depending when/how you installed it, uses `relatime` or `noatime` mount options by default - this means that tracking of access times is basically disabled.

You can change it by removing that option from `/etc/fstab` and rebooting. Or, for instance

```
sudo mount -o remount,atime /home
```

on the relevant filesystem.